# C++ Telegram Bot POST request for updates no result

Tags: c++, curl, bots, telegram

I'm tring to create a telegram bot. I' m first trying to get updates from the bot like said in the Telegram API with /getUpdates method. 
With Postman the request is working good and I have all the data in json format.
Using cUrl I have no response and res is 0. Here there is the snippet of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

static size_t WriteCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
    ((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}


void getUpdates()
{
    std::string readBuffer;

    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.telegram.org/BOTTOKEN/getUpdates");
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_DEFAULT_PROTOCOL, "https");
      struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
      std::cout << "Buffer content"<<readBuffer << std::endl;
      long code = -1;
      curl_easy_getinfo( curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &code );
      std::cout<<"HTTP Response Code: "<< code <<std::endl;
      std::cout<<"Res: "<<res<<std::endl;
      res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    }
}

int main()
{
    getUpdates();
    return 0;
}
```

Buffer content is empty and res is 0.

Could you give me any hints? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it! Here there is the updated code:

```
void getUpdates()
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.telegram.org/botyourtoken/getUpdates");
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_DEFAULT_PROTOCOL, "https");
      struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
      std::string readBuffer;
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
      res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
      std::cout << "Buffer content: "<<std::endl;
      std::cout<<readBuffer << std::endl;
    }
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
```

Thank you!